# Cannot Assign type [String] to type String SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, typing

I'm brand new to Xcode and Swift and I'm running into some typing issues.

So I have a picker list in a view:

```
Picker(selection: $drinkType, label: Text("Drink Type")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< drinks.count) {
                    Text(self.drinks[$0]).tag($0)
                }
```

And I want to have it converted into text so I can display it on a text box, so I need to convert it into a String. My function which takes in these parameters and outputs them is below:

```
    private func addDrink() {
        let drink = Drink(context: context)
        drink.dateDrank = Date()
        drink.drinkType = drinks
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

The issue arises with the drinks variable, it is currently an array you cycle through with the picker:

```
var drinks = ["Pint", "Spirit", "Shot", "Cocktail"]
```

The error it gives me currently is: `Cannot Assign type [String] to Type String`

And when I try to add a String cast: `drink.drinkType = String(drinks)`

The error then thrown my way is: `No exact matches in call to initialiser` and it gives me no pointers to what that could be/mean.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Inside the Picker I added a new variable to store the result:

```
Picker(selection: $drinkType, label: Text("Drink Type")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< type.count) {
                    Text(self.type[$0]).tag($0)
                    AddNewDrink.typeSelected = self.type[$0]
                }
```

So the new function looks like:

```
    private func addDrink() {
        let drink = Drink(context: context)
        drink.dateDrank = Date()
        drink.drinkType = AddNewDrink.typeSelected
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

However the issue now thrown my way is `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'` on the ForEach Loop

Comment: you are trying to cast an array to string. That produces the error. Try using ```drink.drinkType = String(drinks[0])``` or some other value

Comment: Certainly you want to assign **one** type, not the entire array. And probably you want to assign the selected type which is `drinkType`

Comment: @udi I'll try that, although passing in the index gives me a stationary value for the variable at that index. I tried $0 for the movable index but it didn't work.

Comment: @vadian I tried that, assigning drinkType actually assigns the index value, i.e. 0-3

Comment: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create the picker to iterate the strings rather than the indices

```
Picker(selection: $drinkType, label: Text("Drink Type")) {
    ForEach(drinks, id: \.self) { type in 
        Text(type)
    }
}
```

And `drinkType` this way

```
@State private var drinkType = "Pint"
```

Then assign the selected type

```
drink.drinkType = drinkType
```

Side note: `drinks` for the ***type*** array is misleading. A better name is for example just `types`

Comment: Yes I see where it's going but `@State private var drinkType = "Pint"` instead of an array it's not going to iterate through anything as your just assigning it a string. What would then be point of the picker if you can only choose the one option?

It would fix the casting issue but there wouldn't be any other option to choose

Comment: Declaring `drinkType` in Core Data as String attribute implies that there is only one type. `"Pint"` is the default value. If you choose another type from the picker the `@State` property is updated accordingly due to the `selection` Binding